# Neo4j refused to connect

Tags: browser, neo4j, connection

**Characteristics :**

```
Linux 
Neo4j version 3.2.1 
Access on remote
```

**Installation**

I Had install neo4j and gave the folder chmod 777 .
Im running it remotely on my machine and I had already enabled non local access 
Doing NEo4j start i get this message

```
Active database: graph.db
Directories in use:
  home:         /home/cloudera/Muna/apps/neo4j
  config:       /home/cloudera/Muna/apps/neo4j/conf
  logs:         /home/cloudera/Muna/apps/neo4j/logs
  plugins:      /home/cloudera/Muna/apps/neo4j/plugins
  import:       /home/cloudera/Muna/apps/neo4j/import
  data:         /home/cloudera/Muna/apps/neo4j/data
  certificates: /home/cloudera/Muna/apps/neo4j/certificates
  run:          /home/cloudera/Muna/apps/neo4j/run
Starting Neo4j.
WARNING: Max 1024 open files allowed, minimum of 40000 recommended. See the Neo4j manual.
Started neo4j (pid 9469). It is available at http://0.0.0.0:7474/
There may be a short delay until the server is ready.
See /home/cloudera/Muna/apps/neo4j/logs/neo4j.log for current status.
```

and it is not connecting in the browser . 
running neo4j console

```
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (malloc) failed to allocate 409600000 bytes for AllocateHeap
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/cloudera/hs_err_pid18598.log
```

where could  the problem be coming from ?

Comment: Is there something in the log files ?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should set the maximum open files to 40000, which is the recommended value. Then you do not get the WARNING. Like this: http://neo4j.com/docs/1.6.2/configuration-linux-notes.html

Secondly,'failed to allocate memory' means that the Java virtual machine cannot allocate the memory you start it with.
It can be a misconfiguration, or you physically do not have enough memory.
Please read the memory sizing guidelines here:
https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/performance/

Comment: So for example if I have a machine of 16G and I set for the heap 14G and for the pagecache 16gG that should make a problem as in the documentation we have Actual OS allocation = available RAM - (page cache + heap size) right ?

Comment: Yes, this is the official recommendation, if you want to use it for production. Otherwise, you can have problems.